# Recommended .Net Obfuscater for VS 2008?

Tags: .net, obfuscation

Is there a recommended obfuscater for compiled .Net (C#) code that plugs into VS2008?  If not, a stand-alone will do fine, and preferably one that can obfuscate multiple assemblies at once.

I also realize the purpose of these is simply to make it more difficult to reverse-engineer the code... which is exactly what I want.

Thank you.

**Update**: What about enabling strong naming on precompiled assemblies at publishing time?  Is it possible to have point to a key-file on another server?  So as long as that key file is present the app would work??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CodeVeil](http://www.xheo.com/products/codeveil/) is very good, and encrypts the assembly rather than just obfuscating it.

They had issues with 64bit assemblies a couple years ago, but I suspect that they've fixed that by now.

Answer (score 1):

Previous versions of VS came with Dotfuscator.  2008 probably does as well.  Better would probably be to NGen the assemblies if you have controlled deployment environments or an installer that can install the correct assemblies to customer machines.

Answer (score 1):

[Xenocode Postbuild](http://www.xenocode.com/Products/Postbuild-for-NET/) is very good. You can whether obfuscate your assemblies or you can convert them to native code which even doesn't require .NET framework installed.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Crypto Obfuscator](http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/obfuscator-net.htm) for a source code protection (as the free DorFuscator edition is not really usefull for this reason). It can obfusate more assemblies at once and can be itegrated in VS or used as standalone.

I dont know if any software has the pinpoint function you mentioned. You are probably going to make it as a part of your application.